# How does one transform two specific object values into an array of tuple-items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

How can I convert the following object:

```
{
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
}
```

to the following array using Javascript:

```
[
  ["0092T30560", "Bosch"],
  ["0092T30790", "Bosch"],
  ["0092T30800", "Bosch"],
]
```

so after that I can refer to its elements as

`array[0]` and get `["0092T30560", "Bosch"]`

or

`array[1][0]` and get `"0092T30790"`, etc.?

Comment: Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question.

Comment: @Anastasiya ... From all the provided solutions are there any questions left?

Comment: @Anastasiya ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

After having retrieved 2 arrays from an object, the OP wants to merge both arrays into one array of tuple items where each tuple is an array of equally positioned items from both source arrays.

The next provided 1st part of a possible solution utilizes [*Destructuring Assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#nested_object_and_array_destructuring) with renaming ...

```js
const sampleData = {
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
};
const {
  Articul: articleIdList,
  Brand: brandNameList,
} = sampleData;

console.log({
  articleIdList,
  brandNameList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The step of merging the above two arrays into one can be achieved by either a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

As for the mapping, one can make use of the [`map`'s second `thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail), thus while getting provided current `item` and `idx` of the processed array one in addition can access the second array through the callbacks `this` context ...

```js
const sampleData = {
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
};
const {
  Articul: articleIdList,
  Brand: brandNameList,
} = sampleData;

function createTupleFromBoundList (item, idx) {
  // `item` ... current item of `articleIdList`.
  // `idx` ... position of the currently processed item.
  // `this` ... `brandNameList` provided as `thisArg`.
  return [item, this[idx]];
}
const articleAndBrandTupleList =
  articleIdList.map(createTupleFromBoundList, brandNameList);

console.log({ articleAndBrandTupleList });


// ... or, since the approach is known now, the direct notation ... ...
console.log(`sampleData.Articul
  .map(createTupleFromBoundList, sampleData.Brand) ...`,

  sampleData.Articul
    .map(createTupleFromBoundList, sampleData.Brand)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As for the `reduce` based approach, one needs to provide the second array as part of a collector/accumulator object which will be passed as the [reducer function's initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) ...

```js
const sampleData = {
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
};
const {
  Articul: articleIdList,
  Brand: brandNameList,
} = sampleData;

function createAndCollectTuple(collector, item, idx) {
  // `item` ... current item of `articleIdList`.
  // `idx` ... position of the currently processed item.
  collector.result.push([
    item,
    collector.secondList[idx],
  ]);
  return collector;
}
const articleAndBrandTupleList =
  articleIdList.reduce(createAndCollectTuple, {

    secondList: brandNameList,
    result: [],

  }).result;

console.log({ articleAndBrandTupleList });


// ... or, since the approach is known now, the direct notation ...
console.log(`sampleData.Articul
  .reduce(createAndCollectTuple, {

    secondList: sampleData.Brand,
    result: [],

  }).result ...`,

  sampleData.Articul
    .reduce(createAndCollectTuple, {

      secondList: sampleData.Brand,
      result: [],

    }).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try at least something, anyway you could do it by following this approach :

- Get Articuls and Brands by using `object-destructuring`
- Go through Articuls get the value as the key and its value from Brands array according to the key of articuls.

```js
obj = {
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
}
let {Articul: Articuls, Brand: Brands} = obj;
let array = Articuls.map((Articul, key)=>[Articul, Brands[i]]);
```

Results:

```
array[0] // ["0092T30560", "Bosch"]
array[1][0] //0092T30790
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const object = {
  Articul: ["0092T30560", "0092T30790", "0092T30800"],
  Brand: ["Bosch", "Bosch", "Bosch"],
};

const modified_obj = object.Articul.map((item, index) => {
  return [
    item,
    object.Brand[index],
  ];
});
console.log(modified_obj);
```